# Word VBA: Show {FILENAME} on the last page of each section after Word MailMerge

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word

I'm trying to make a Word MailMerge where the last page of the section (i.e. the last page of every letter) has a field code

```
{FILENAME}
```

Word's MailMerge aggressively computes any field code it finds, so I have been post-processing the resulting document. I tried putting this formula in

```
{IF {PAGE} = {SECTIONPAGES} {FILENAME}}
```

but this got calculated and replaced during the MailMerge (So I had 'Document1' everywhere). IF Functions get calculated and set to their result, so I searched again and found a hint by macropod showing a tricky workaround using the # switch where you're abusing the function (in the case below it uses different formats, separated by semicolons, with the order being positive value, negative value, and 0.

```
{={SECTIONPAGES}-{PAGE} \# ";;'{FILENAME}'"}
```

But this failed too. The field code remained a field code, but unfortunately {FILENAME} was calculated, so I ended up with a function in my final mailmerged document looking like this:

```
{={SECTIONPAGES}-{PAGE} \# ";;'Document1'"}
```

Day-amm. So now I am putting an arbitrary text placeholder in the field code. This does not get changed by the MailMerge.

```
{={SECTIONPAGES}-{PAGE} \# ";;'PlaceholderText'"}
```

Now I am trying to replace this text with the actual field, and using this code:

```
Application.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 10 'wdSeekCurrentPageFooter

Set footerRange = Application.Selection.Range
footerRange.Find.Text = "PlaceholderText"
While footerRange.Find.Execute()
   MsgBox "found it"
   Call Application.Selection.Fields.Add(footerRange, 29)
Wend

Application.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 0
```

but it's looping continuously. I'm aware that I can add a field only to a selection, or a range, but have been unable to get this to work correctly.

P.s. @Bibadia, this is a follow-up to my previous question, I thought it better to ask another question.

Comment: so, the only problem of yours is to stop continuous looping? have you tried to work with parameters `.Forward = True` and `.Wrap = wdFindAsk` or others? you could also use extended syntax for find as described [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839118%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and in other web pages.

Comment: @KazJaw the problem is one of selection. I want to find a text (this happens), then replace that text with a field code (that is not happening). The find method is not actually making a selection, I think.

Comment: I haven't tried to replicate, but I suggest you try footerRange.fields.add footerrange, 29 instead of the Selection.

Comment: bibadia, tried that but did not work. At the moment I think that there is a difference between 'plain old text' and 'text that has been generated by a field code'.